# Is there a fast way to replace two map contents?

Tags: c++, swap

In my code I have a map which holds a large amount of data (~100MB) I need to copy all that data from one map to another. currently I am doing this with swap [but to my understanding](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/swap/), swap is a fancy way to do a copy. Is there a way to simply transfer the memory used by the two maps? I think that I can do this with pointers but I was hoping for a more elegant way.

Comment: No, `std::map::swap` really does just swap the pointers, and not do a copy. (But if you used `std::swap`, then that _will_ do a copy.)

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung: 23.4.1.5 [map.special] says that `std::swap` for two maps `x` and `y` must be specialized to do the equivalent of `x.swap(y)`. There should be no difference. (I'm not stalking you!)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well, once again, you're right. Hat tip, etc. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless this came up in a profiler run as a bottleneck, you may be optimizing prematurely.

My compiler's `std::map::swap()` has the following comment, which indicates that a map swap is likely to be very fast:

```
  /**
   *  This exchanges the elements between two maps in constant
   *  time.  (It is only swapping a pointer, an integer, and an
   *  instance of the @c Compare type (which itself is often
   *  stateless and empty), so it should be quite fast.)  Note
   *  that the global std::swap() function is specialized such
   *  that std::swap(m1,m2) will feed to this function.
   */
```

(`g++ 4.4.5`)

Answer (score 5):

23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] of ISO/IEC 14882:2011 contains a list of general container requirements. For all standard containers the expressions `a.swap(b)` and `swap(a, b)` must exchange the contents of `a` and `b` and for all standard containers other than `array` both must have constant time. This effectively means that swapping maps cannot involve copying all the map elements.

Comment: @Yotam: I'm not sure what you mean. My answer is an answer to your question. No action required.

Comment: both your answer and aix answer are helpfull and I have used both your answer to extend my (misserable) understanding of my code/c++ programming. I want to give both you and aix the creddit for it

Comment: @Yotam: I already have too much credit. Accepting aix's answer seems fair to me.